# How to count and hide element after n number?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following html

```
   <div id="area">
     <p>Paragraph one</p>
     <p>Paragraph two</p>
     <p>Paragraph three</p>
     <p>Paragraph four</p>
     <p>Paragraph five</p>
     <p>Paragraph six</p>
   </div>
```

I need to `hide` all `<p>` tags after the `first one` and have a ream more/read less button.

I know I can count the elements by doing:

```
var count = $("#area").find("p").length;
if(count > 1) {

}
```

But how would I go into inserting a read more/less?

Trying to achieve a show/hide to toggle display block/none:

```
   <div id="area">
     <p>Paragraph one</p>
     <button type="button">Read more</button>
     <p style="display: none;">Paragraph two</p>
     <p style="display: none;">Paragraph three</p>
     <p style="display: none;">Paragraph four</p>
     <p style="display: none;">Paragraph five</p>
     <p style="display: none;">Paragraph six</p>
   </div>
```

Comment: you want to hide all the p tags??

Comment: yes, trying to have a show/hide of all the p tags after the first one @Ashishsah

Comment: Is this <p> tags dynamically generated?

Comment: yes they are @sampathwijesinghe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use jQuerys `.slice()` function to select all p-tags after the first one. And `after` to add the Read More Link.

```
var $ps = $("#area").children("p");
$ps.slice(1).hide(); // hide all p-tags after the first one
// add the read more after the first element
$ps.eq(0).after($('<button type="button">Read more</button>').click(function(){
    // if the read more link is clicked, remove the read more link and show all p-tags
    $(this).remove();
    $ps.show();
}));
```

Comment: What does `eq(0)` do? I've never seen that before on jQuery.

Comment: @cgTag eq(X) selects the Xth element out of the jQuery collection: http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Comment: Nice. I'll have to remember that one.

Comment: p.s. the <a> tag wouldn't be semantic tho, better use <button> *

Comment: yes sure, but since it is not linking to anything and for any future user, i'd insert a <button> as per the question. Just saying hey, apart from that, works perfectly

Answer (score 2):

1. Use the [`:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) selector to get the first child of area.
2. Use the jQuery [`after`](https://api.jquery.com/after/) method to add a button.
3. Use the jQuery [`nextAll`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) method to [hide](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) all `p` tags after the first.
4. Within the [click event](https://api.jquery.com/click/) of the button [hide](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) the button and show all the `p` tags.

```js
$("#area")
  .children("p:first-child")
  .after($("<button/>")
    .text("Read More")
    .click(function() {
      $(this).hide().siblings("p").show();
    }))
  .nextAll("p")
  .hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="area">
  <p>Paragraph one</p>
  <p>Paragraph two</p>
  <p>Paragraph three</p>
  <p>Paragraph four</p>
  <p>Paragraph five</p>
  <p>Paragraph six</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're going to get so many answers for this one:

```
var items = $("p");
if(items.length > 1) {
    items.hide().first().show();
    var btn = $("<button type="button">Read more</button>")
          .on('click',function() {
               items.show();
          });
    items.first().after(btn);
}
```

It really depends if you want to use mostly JavaScript, mostly CSS or mostly existing HTML.

**CSS Tips**:

```
// hide all paragraphs that are in pairs, because <button> is after first
p + p { display: none; }
```

Actually, that's all I could think of. lol

Comment: this is nice too, how would you do it with css only? I was looking into ellipse but couldn't see any read more option without to use js

Comment: You'd need JS to set some CSS classes. I'll update with some tips.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with something like this:

```
$("#area p").slice(1).addClass("hide");
$("#area p")[0].append("<a>Show More</a>");
```

I understand this might not look well, but I hope you get the gist.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution you can test:

In css code:

```
#area p{display:none;}
```

In jquery code:

```
$("#area p:first-child).show();
$("button").click(function(){
$("#area p).show();
});
```

Comment: yeah ok but where is the button?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this: https://jsbin.com/xuhuduqawi/edit?html,js,output
I have added a class in your first para. It's simple and easy to understand. Add Js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".more").click(function(){
 $("p").show();
 });
$(".less").click(function(){
  $("p").hide();
  $(".first").show();
});
});
```

and your hyml have been changed to:

```
  <div id="area">
 <p class="first">Paragraph one</p>
 <p>Paragraph two</p>
 <p>Paragraph three</p>
 <p>Paragraph four</p>
 <p>Paragraph five</p>
 <p>Paragraph six</p>
 </div>
<button class="more">more </button>
<button class="less">less</button>
```

Comment: I hope this helps

Comment: hi yes it helps, yet i am not able to give an id to the first p

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, an alternate solution

```
$("#area").wrapInner($("<div class='hide-area'>"));
$('div.hide-area').each(function(){
  $(this).children().first().prependTo($(this).closest("#area")).after("<a href='#' id='toggle-display' >Read more... </a>");
});
$('div.hide-area').css("display", 'none');
$("#toggle-display").click(function(){
    $(".hide-area").toggle();
});
```

check this on fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wjd6ysym/5/)

Comment: thanks, try hiding the rest of the <p> tags tho to make it a complete example